# Why am I getting "The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+XML" error?

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;

public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]){

    try {
        WordExtractor extractor = new WordExtractor(new FileInputStream("/Users/testuser/myworddoc.docx"));
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

When executing this code I get the following error message:

"The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+XML.  You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data."

How do I modify the code to resolve this issue?

Comment: It's not that hard: http://poi.apache.org/document/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like WordExtractor expects your doc in Office 2007 format, so either save your doc in the expected format or find the equivalent process to deal with your doc.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It's the other way around.